# time - how to get hours difference in php?

Tags: php

I have two different time first is - **06:15 PM**  & second is - **07:15 PM**

I want time difference answer: **1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
 $ts1 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '02/01/2013 06:15'));
        $ts2 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '02/01/2013 07.15'));
        echo $diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
```

You can learn more about strtotime method in php it really helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, i.e.:

```
// create DateTime objects from string
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i A', "06:15 PM");
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i A',"07:15 PM");
// determine what interval should be used - Hours in this case
$interval = new \DateInterval('PT1H');
// create hourly periods between the two dates
$periods = new \DatePeriod($date1, $interval, $date2);
// count the number of objects within the periods
$hours = iterator_count($periods);
echo $hours;
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Php has a function for determining the difference between two datetime objects. There are some good examples of how to use the function in the documentation comments.
[PHP manual datetime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

You can use the formatting options shown in the pages comments to get just the hours (%H I believe is what you would need)

Answer (score 0):

```
                     <?php  
                             $one="06:15 PM";
                             $two="07:45 PM";

                             $one_time = strtotime($one);
                             $two_time = strtotime($two);


         echo $minutes= round(abs($one_time - $two_time) / 60,2); //diff in minutes
         echo $hours =$currDate . " " . gmdate("H:i", ($minutes * 60));//diff in hours

                          ?>
```